# How to read pixels of an image in c?

Tags: c

> Suppose our bitmap image has height M and width N. We'll always assume
>   in this lab that the width N is a multiple of 4, which simplifies the
>   byte layout in the file. For this image, the pixel array stores
>   exactly 3 x N x M bytes, in the following way:
>
> Each group of 3 bytes represents a single pixel, where the bytes store
>   the blue, green, and red colour values of the pixel, in that order.
>
> Pixels are grouped by row. For example, the first 3 x N bytes in the
>   pixel array represent the pixels in the top-most row of the image.

`pixel_array_offset` is where the pixel array starts.

A struct pixel is given as following:

```
struct pixel {
    unsigned char blue;
    unsigned char green;
    unsigned char red;
};
```

And here is the requirement for implementing the function:

```
/*
 * Read in pixel array by following these instructions:
 *
 * 1. First, allocate space for m "struct pixel *" values, where m is the
 *    height of the image.  Each pointer will eventually point to one row of
 *    pixel data.
 * 2. For each pointer you just allocated, initialize it to point to
 *    heap-allocated space for an entire row of pixel data.
 * 3. ...
 * 4. ...
 */
struct pixel **read_pixel_array(FILE *image, int pixel_array_offset, int width, int height) {

}
```

For the first step, allocate space for m "struct pixel *" values. I think it is actually allocating space for an array of pixel values. So I put

```
unsigned char **ptrs = height * malloc(sizeof(struct pixel));
```

For the second step, I don't quite understand what I should do. I think I need  a for loop to allocate space for all rows of pixel data. But I have no idea what I should put inside.

```
for (int i=0, i<height, i++) {

        }
```

Comment: Are you sure your image is unsigned char? Meaning all pixel values are between values of 0-255? You should make it templated, so it works with many different imagery. Many images can be Unsigned Short, short, float, and need to be allocated a certain way. To allocate for your pixel array, you need something like: unsigned char* image = new unsigned char[width_of_image * height_of_image]. Also how are you reading this GDAL, libjpg, libnt2. There are many different types of imagery. Each have their own libraries you need for lower level of opening the headers to get metadata/reading

Comment: Watch out: for a BMP image the row length in file is always a multiple of 4 bytes: known as the *stride*. So if the image is 11 pixels wide, the 33 BGR bytes needs 36 bytes of storage. Your example dodges the issue with *"We'll always assume in this lab that the width N is a multiple of 4, which simplifies the byte layout in the file."*

Comment: unsigned char is given, except the line I write in the first step.

Comment: @ Weather Vane I don't familiar with the image. But I just add more requirement information at the beginning. Hope that will make you more clear.

Comment: Yeah I edited the comment, which explains why you have been given that simplification.

Comment: The first step is allocating space for an array of pointers to each row memory. Then you allocate memory to each of the those pointers for an array of `struct`s.

Comment: So technically *first step, allocate space for* `m "struct pixel *"`. How does `m x struct pixel *` become `unsigned char **ptrs`? Perhaps `struct pixel **ptrs`? (now technically you are fine by happy accident because a *pointer-is-a-pointer-is-a-pointer*, and since it is a `char` type you don't run afoul of *strict aliasing*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want to allocate a 2D array, you first need to allocate an array of `struct pixel *`:

```
struct pixel **ptrs = malloc(height * sizeof(struct pixel*));
```

There are several changes here to note:

1. You are allocating pointers to `struct pixel`, not `unsigned char`.
2. `malloc()` returns a pointer. Multiplying a pointer by an integer is invalid.
3. The multiplication goes in the parentheses because it helps calculate the correct number of bytes to allocate.

Next you need to allocate an array of `struct pixel` for each row in the 2D array:

```
for (int i=0, i<height, i++) {
    ptrs[i] = malloc(width * sizeof(struct pixel));
}
```

Now the array is completely allocated and you can fill it in with data:

```
ptrs[5][6] = { 255, 0, 0}; // a blue pixel
```

Finally remember to `free()` all of your pointers before you exit your program:

```
for (int i=0, i<height, i++) {
    free(ptrs[i]);
}

free(ptrs);
```

Comment: Here the question is about reading data from the 2d array. But you mentioned writing into it. Please do write the code for reading the data from 2d array.

Comment: @AdityaRao The question is about allocating memory, not about reading nor writing. Once all the pointers are allocated, you read and write the same way you do a static array.